# Artifacts when playing a video

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, video, ffmpeg, visual-artifacts

When I play a video with mpv (xubuntu 18.04 LTS), every couple of minutes, there are what I'd call a "keyframe" artifacts.

Basically it seem like the video failed to decode a keyframe and continues to interpolate inbetweens from previous frame. It usually goes away with the next successful keframe. What is weird that it affects only bottom half of the frame.

I've tried running `mpv --msg-level=all=v` but it doesn't show any error there.
Here's what it looks like when I managed to pause when it happened:
[image: example]

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$ uname -roms
Linux 4.15.0-54-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ffmpeg 
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
$ mpv --version
mpv 0.27.2 (C) 2000-2017 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
 built on UNKNOWN
ffmpeg library versions:
   libavutil       55.78.100
   libavcodec      57.107.100
   libavformat     57.83.100
   libswscale      4.8.100
   libavfilter     6.107.100
   libswresample   2.9.100
ffmpeg version: 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 10
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [17aa:21fa]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

I believe it happens with vlc too, but I cannot confirm that right now. It happens with matroska (maybe other too, haven't tested yet) media from internal hdd. It doesn't happen with streaming media from web browser.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: - is this a recent development, or has it always been like this?
- are you playing the media from an internal system drive or remote storage or streaming?
- Nvidia or AMD graphics drivers?

Comment: It is a long standing issue. It's a file played from internal hdd. And it's a integrated intel gpu. I've edited main post with some more details.